# How to customize formatting warning in Webclipse for Angular 2 Typescript?

Tags: eclipse, angular, typescript, web-clips

Webclipse gives a lot for formatting warning for the Typescript code, for example, for blank spaces and for using double quotes instead of single quotes.  The latter one is annoying since using double quotes for strings is quite appropriate.

Is it possible to customize these warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that the Webclipse setting for warnings are in the file tslint.json in the root directory of the Angular application.  The easiest way to change these settings is to use the Eclipse Quick Fix option, and then use the hint to remove this warning from tslint.json.